# HTTP Error 500 while using imagettftext in php

Tags: php

I am trying to generate and display an image in php. But i am getting the HTTP Error 500 : Unexpected Condition encountered..... When i broke the code and retried several times, i figured out that the error was at the line where i used imagettftext. My php version is 5.3.15 and below is my code.

```
$image = @imagecreate(120, 40) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
putenv('GDFONTPATH='.realpath('.'));
$font = 'arial';
imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 10, 10, $black, $font , 'Print');
```

I have arial.ttf file in the same directory where the php file is present. I doubt the error is because php is unable to locate the font file.
Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: have you tried `$font = 'arial.ttf';`?

Comment: What does `var_dump(function_exists('imagettftext'));` output?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller : var_dump(function_exists('imagettftext')); returns bool(false). What does that mean? The function is not available in my php version. I have a macbook which comes by default with php. What can be the resolution for it?

Comment: Thanks Chris for pointing out that. I got this in the error log. "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagettftext()". Do i need to especially download any library to use the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no TTF support in your php instalation. To enable TTF support, php must be configured with one of the following options: `--with-freetype-dir=DIR` `--with-t1lib[=DIR]` `--enable-gd-native-ttf`

[Read more  about GD instalation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)

Comment: Thanks dev-null-dweller, going through the documentation!